# How do you calculate using sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying something like this:

```
select sum(R_Value) ,((5/cast(sum(R_Value) as int)) * 100.000000000) 
from R_Rating 
where R_B_Id = 135
```

But I keep getting value 0, sum(R_Value) = 6, so I just want a percentage out of (5/sum(R_Value)) * 100.

How can I get this?

I have a rating of 5 so each user has a rating they can make select from 1 to 5, so what i need is a formula that takes in the sum and takes into account how many users have rated and give us a result from 1 to 5 in the end

Something like this may work but i need to round up to one decimal place to get a whole number.

```
select sum(R_Value), ((count(*)/cast(sum(R_Value) as float)) * 10) 
from R_Rating 
where R_B_Id = 135
```

Comment: What's the expected result? I think you may want to **multiply** by 5 and **divide** by 100, but it's not clear for the skimp description.

Comment: an INT divided by an INT returns an INT  ...   So for example Select 5/10 returns 0.   HOWEVER  Select 5/10.0 returns 0.5000

Comment: Updated please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the average rating you need to force floating point algebra. For example:

```
select 1.0 * sum(R_Value) / count(*)
from R_Rating 
where R_B_Id = 135
```

Then, if your query selects three rows with the values: `1`, `4`, and `5`, then this query will return `3.33` stars as the average. That is:

```
= 1.0 * (1 + 4 + 5) / 3
= 1.0 * 10 / 3
= 10.0 / 3
= 3.33333333
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing this as:

```
select sum(R_Value) ,
      (500.0 / sum(R_Value))
from R_Rating 
where R_B_Id = 135;
```

This avoids an integer division.